# Classify real-time video with TensorFlow

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm using this tutorial to get started with TensorFlow - 
[TensorFlow for poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0).

After training the model using the retrain.py script, I want to use the 
retrained_graph.pb in order to classify a video and see the results live while the video is running.

What I did is to use opencv to read the video which I want to classify frame by frame. i.e read a frame, save it, open it, classify it and show it on screen together with the classification result using cv2.imshow().

It works, but due to the reading and writing of the frames from/to the disk, the resulting video is laggy.

Can I use the graph obtained from the training process and classify a video without reading and saving it frame by frame?

This is the code I'm using -

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
i = 0
while True:
    frame = video_capture.read()[1] # get current frame
    frameId = video_capture.get(1) #current frame number
    i = i + 1
    cv2.imwrite(filename="C:\\video_images\\"+ str(i) +".jpg", img=frame) # write frame image to file
    image_data = "C:\\video_images\\" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    t = read_tensor_from_image_file(image_data,
                                    input_height=input_height,
                                    input_width=input_width,
                                    input_mean=input_mean,
                                    input_std=input_std)
    predictions = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
    scores = []
    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        scores.append([score, human_string])
        #print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
    #print("\n\n")
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame, scores[0][1] + " - " + repr(round(scores[0][0], 2)), (10, 50), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, scores[1][1] + " - " + repr(round(scores[1][0], 2)), (10, 100), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow("image", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    os.remove("C:\\video_images\\" + str(i) + ".jpg")

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of showing each frame alongside with prediction process, you want to record prediction results as a video. Am I right?

Comment: Just wants to process the video through the classifier without being having to write each frame to disk and then read it in a loop.

Comment: You are reading from video file-writing frame to disk-reading from disk-performing prediction-showing prediction outputs. Why do you even bother to write frame data just to read it afterwards? It is already inside the memory. Instead do the processing that is done in `read_tensor_from_image_file` on `frame` itself and pass `frame` to session.

Comment: That's the point, I'm not able to make read_tensor_from_image_file to work directly on the frame :(

Comment: Well, [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ba730a4f6de09ab8635091517933462dc70e4443/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py#L38) is the source for the said function. It just reads from file and performs normalization. Take the frame and normalize it then pass the frame to session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it.

Edited read_tensor_from_image_file to the following and just fed it with the frame instead of image_data.

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                            input_height=299,
                            input_width=299,
                            input_mean=0,
                            input_std=255):
input_name = "file_reader"
output_name = "normalized"

if type(file_name) is str:
    file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
    if file_name.endswith(".png"):
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                           name='png_reader')
    elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
        image_reader = tf.squeeze(tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader,
                                                      name='gif_reader'))
    elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name='bmp_reader')
    else:
        image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3,
                                            name='jpeg_reader')
    float_caster = tf.cast(image_reader, tf.float32)
    dims_expander = tf.expand_dims(float_caster, 0);
    resized = tf.image.resize_bilinear(dims_expander, [input_height,
                                                       input_width])
    normalized = tf.divide(tf.subtract(resized, [input_mean]), 
                           [input_std])
    sess = tf.Session()
    result = sess.run(normalized)

elif type(file_name) is np.ndarray:
    resized = cv2.resize(file_name, (input_width, input_height),
                            interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    normalized = (resized - input_mean) / input_std
    result = normalized
    result = array(result).reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)

return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frame = video_capture.read()[1] # get current frame
float_caster = frame.astype(np.float32)
dims_expander = np.expand_dims(float_caster, axis=0)
resized = cv2.resize(dims_expander,(int(input_width),int(input_height)))
normalized = (resized - input_mean) / input_std
predictions = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {input_operation.outputs[0]: normalized})
```

Instead of using `imwrite` just to call `read_tensor_from_image_file`, get the frame itself. Resize and normalize it. Then, pass the `normalized` into session. Get rid of disk unnecessary write/read operations this way.

Comment: This gives me the following error - 
`TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("truediv:0", shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) which was passed to the feed with key Tensor("import/input:0", shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32).`

Comment: Uh, that was my wrong, sorry. I do not have TF so I cannot test this out. You cannot feed `tf.Tensor` to session. But, I used TF methods which return of type `tf.Tensor`. Just use NumPy and OpenCV equivalent of each function and you are good to go.